# SSIS Script Task - input string was not in a correct format

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have a very very strange issue going on with SSIS and wanted to know if anyone else has had something similar.

In a Data Flow I have a Source that gets data from a MSSQL table and then feeds it to a data transformation Script Task.

The script task is as follows:

**Script Task**

```
public override void Input0_ProcessInputRow(Input0Buffer Row)
{
    string SecurityHeader = (string)Variables.SecurityHeader;
    string APIToken = (string)Variables.APIToken;
    var AppFormID = (string)Row.AppFormID;
    var AppClassName = (string)Row.AppClassName;
    var Lat = Row.Latitude;
    var Long = Row.Longitude;

    var data = new
    {
        record = new
        {
            status = Row.Status.ToString(),
            latitude = Row.Latitude,
            longitude = Row.Longitude,
            form_values = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        }
    };

    if (Row.CreatedBy_IsNull == false) { data.record.form_values["1a09"] = Row.CreatedBy.ToString(); }

    string jsonstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    var client = new RestClient(AppURLRef);
    var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
    request.AddHeader(SecurityHeader, APIToken);
    request.AddHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.AddParameter("application/json", jsonstring, ParameterType.RequestBody);

    try
    {
        IRestResponse dataresponse = client.Execute(request);
        if (dataresponse.StatusCode.ToString() == "Created")
        {
            var listobject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Lists>(dataresponse.Content);
        }
        else
        {
            Row.OErrorMsg = dataresponse.ErrorMessage.ToString();
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + "  Data: " + ex.Data + "   Inner Exception:  " + ex.InnerException);
    }
}
```

**The Issue**

When I run this without any break points I get a Message Box with the error *"Input string was not in correct format"*

Where this gets really weird is that when I put a break point in the code works perfectly, thus making getting a line error impossible.

Has anyone ever come across an issue like this before and if so how did you fix it?

**Update**

After following some advice I moved the try catch block up to the start of the script, this resulted in no change the try catch block was never hit.

I attempted to but a `MessageBox.Show("")` at the very top of the input process row and again this was not hit. Something is happening at a higher level than both of these thought I am unable to find out where or how this is occurring.

Again to reiterate the error is in a MessageBox, not in the output and nothing gets logged in the process tab. So this means no line numbers, no useful error messages that discusses where this error is occurring.

Comment: when error popup it will shows the line no. also, can you check the data type of both the conversion part, it should a have proper value to get convert.

Comment: Not sure about the breakpoint affecting the failure/success but try expanding the scope of your try block. Move the opening statement to the line preceding `string SecurityHeader`

Comment: @billinkc - Good idea but again no go, included the entire script and nothing. I also added a message box at the very top of the script and it never gets hit for some reason. There is something going on at a higher level... just not sure where

Comment: @sumngh Afraid not, if I had a line number I wouldn't be asking this question

Comment: Define "nothing" It errored or no error was encountered?

Comment: In these situations I prune code out to isolate the issue. So I suggest you remove the try catch completely and the web service call inside it. Same message or not? SSIS Script task has a lot of weirdness that makes it not quite the same as a normal piece of coding written in visual studio.

Comment: Of course if the message disappears, remove other pieces like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` and `dataresponse.StatusCode.ToString()` and isolate the line. This will hopefully give you the line in the code that is causing the issue (which ostensibly appears to occur before the code is actually run).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to solve this, after commenting **EVERYTHING** out and removing all of the input columns the error was still occurring.

I put it down to another way Microsoft wants to punish me, I copied the code deleted the script task, added a new script task and copied the old code back in. Worked perfectly...

Thanks Microsoft!!

Answer (score 0):

Put delay in catch block in next line to MessageBox.Show

you able to view message box .

Some time message box goes in back ground (  USe ALT +TAB to find it).

Comment: Thanks @sandeep rawat - This isn't the issue though, it never gets into the try catch block, it is hitting something much earlier and why setting a break point fixes it is even odder.